# Android WebRTC setRemoteDescription

Tags: java, android, websocket, webrtc

I'm trying to implement an RTC in my Android app.
My Android client is meant to be the offer.

I use setLocalDescription and send my SessionDescription.
The problem is when I create my own SessionDescription and try to use setRemoteDescription - I get a response that my SessionDescription is null although is isn't.
See the following code.

```
public class OfferActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final private String TAG = "App";

    private PeerConnectionFactory mFactory;
    private PeerConnection mPeerConnection;
    private DataChannel mDataChannel;
    private MediaConstraints mConstraints;

    PeerConnection.Observer mPeerConnectionObserver = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
            IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(iceCandidate.sdpMid, iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex, "candidate");  // TODO: Edit
            Log.d(TAG, "pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: " + candidate.toString());
            mPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
            mDataChannel = dataChannel;
            mDataChannel.registerObserver(mDataChannelObserver);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        }
    };

    DataChannel.Observer mDataChannelObserver = new DataChannel.Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChange() {
            Log.d(TAG, "mDataChannelObserver onStateChange() " + mDataChannel.state().name());

            if (mDataChannel.state() == DataChannel.State.OPEN) {
                String data = mEt.getText().toString();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes());
                mDataChannel.send(new DataChannel.Buffer(buffer, false));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mDataChannelObserver onMessage()");
            if (buffer.binary == false) {
                int limit = buffer.data.limit();
                byte[] datas = new byte[limit];
                buffer.data.get(datas);
                final String tmp = new String(datas);
                Log.d(TAG, "mDataChannelObserver onMessage: " + tmp);
                addText("mDataChannelObserver", tmp);
            }
        }
    };

    SdpObserver mSdpLocalObserver = new SdpObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription desc) {

            final SessionDescription.Type typeEnum = desc.type;
            final String type = typeEnum.canonicalForm();
            final String sdp = desc.description;

            if (typeEnum == SessionDescription.Type.OFFER) {
                mPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(mSdpLocalObserver, desc);
                // TODO: Here we will have the code that gets the other peer sdp
            } else if (typeEnum == SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER) {
                mPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(mSdpLocalObserver, desc);
            } else {


                Log.d(TAG, "Something else was found at onCreateSuccess");
            }
            // TODO: This is debug only. the "setLocalDescription" does not need javascript interfaces (JSON)
            try {
                final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("type", type);
                json.put("sdp", sdp);
                Log.d(TAG, "mSdpLocalObserver onCreateSuccess() > sdp: " + json.toString());
            } catch (org.json.JSONException ex) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "mSdpLocalObserver onCreateSuccess()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mSdpLocalObserver onCreateFailure() " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mSdpLocalObserver onSetFailure() " + s);
        }
    };

    private TextView mTv;
    private EditText mEt;
    private Button mBtn;
    private EditText mEtRegister;
    private Button mBtnRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTv);
        mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEt);
        mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtn);
        mEtRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEtRegister);
        mBtnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnRegister);
        mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(getApplicationContext(), true, true, true, null);
        mFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory();

        final List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new LinkedList<>();
        iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:xx.xx.xxx.xxx")); // TODO: Edit

        mConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        mConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
        mConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "true"));

        mPeerConnecti

                on = mFactory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, mConstraints, mPeerConnectionObserver);

        mDataChannel = mPeerConnection.createDataChannel("test", new DataChannel.Init()); // TODO: Edit


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        if (mDataChannel != null) {
            mDataChannel.close();
            mDataChannel.unregisterObserver();
        }
        if (mPeerConnection != null) {
            mPeerConnection.close();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mBtnRegister) {
            String text = mEtRegister.getText().toString(); // .replace("\\r\\n","");
            final SessionDescription description = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER, text);
            mPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(mSdpLocalObserver, null);
        }
    }

    private DataChannel.Buffer send(String data) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes());
        return new DataChannel.Buffer(buffer, false);
    }

    private void addText(final String who, final String what) {
        OfferActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String text = mTv.getText().toString() + "\n";
                mTv.setText(text + who + ": " + what);
                mEt.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My Logs:

```
01-19 16:12:51.447 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onRenegotiationNeeded()
01-19 16:12:51.879 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onSignalingChange() HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER
01-19 16:12:51.881 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: mSdpLocalObserver onCreateSuccess() > sdp: {"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 8050881100630094562 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE data\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=application 9 RTP\/SAVPF 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nb=AS:30\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:+f0buF4V2OXNT4sI\r\na=ice-pwd:\/QDilxDBndczNuvgPIBXZ7je\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E4:FB:1E:80:16:B8:4E:F9:B1:E3:81:B6:09:83:95:F3:B3:C2:34:DC:88:F4:C8:DF:9B:50:8A:00:0E:4D:AC:75\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:data\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:101 google-data\/90000\r\na=ssrc:1715303496 cname:NVNcmn2VpGpsfyFJ\r\na=ssrc:1715303496 msid:test test\r\na=ssrc:1715303496 mslabel:test\r\na=ssrc:1715303496 label:test\r\n"}
01-19 16:12:51.882 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() GATHERING
01-19 16:12:51.883 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() GATHERING
01-19 16:12:51.883 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: sdpObserver1 onCreateSuccess()
01-19 16:12:51.884 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:51.885 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:51.985 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:51.986 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:52.038 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:52.039 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:12:52.039 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() COMPLETE
01-19 16:13:32.985 9171-9239/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: sdpObserver1 onSetFailure() SessionDescription is NULL.
01-19 16:14:16.864 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onRenegotiationNeeded()
01-19 16:14:16.974 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onSignalingChange() HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER
01-19 16:14:16.977 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: mSdpLocalObserver onCreateSuccess() > sdp: {"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 3146545619962464613 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE data\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=application 9 RTP\/SAVPF 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nb=AS:30\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:W3sKNep8dXP\/Ind5\r\na=ice-pwd:oOy9NblGeZxRWL\/bxSnFU8KD\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 78:2E:EF:58:AD:11:E3:29:34:7C:94:48:E7:DC:98:90:17:D6:5E:0B:DC:72:3E:4A:5A:35:7F:C5:F8:D4:06:81\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:data\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:101 google-data\/90000\r\na=ssrc:3989867427 cname:JKXfZ0vrlT1jdURT\r\na=ssrc:3989867427 msid:test test\r\na=ssrc:3989867427 mslabel:test\r\na=ssrc:3989867427 label:test\r\n"}
01-19 16:14:16.978 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() GATHERING
01-19 16:14:16.978 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() GATHERING
01-19 16:14:16.978 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: sdpObserver1 onCreateSuccess()
01-19 16:14:16.980 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:16.981 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:17.082 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:17.082 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:17.136 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:17.137 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceCandidate() param: data:0:candidate
01-19 16:14:17.138 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onIceGatheringChange() COMPLETE
01-19 16:14:22.769 11776-11844/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: sdpObserver1 onSetFailure() SessionDescription is NULL.
01-19 16:31:51.241 29355-29414/com.walkme.rtc D/sample: pcObserver1 onRenegotiationNeeded()
```

**EDIT**

After further inspection the problem was with the codecs.
What I did was simply get the data as a string of json and then used JsonObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of sdp you received. The webrtc lib for web browser use JSON object as the sdp format but string for android. So when you receive your sdp string from remote, it may contain JSON code.

Print your sdp string. If it looks like JSON format, turn it into JSON Object and get the sdp string inside.

```
//data is JSONObject received from signal server.
try {
    sdpJSON = new JSONObject(data.optString("sdp"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String sdp = sdpJSON.optString("sdp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem when I setLocalSDP, and got a setFailure back with the messge "session is null".
I checked my code and find the AudioTrack and AudioSource ID string I set contains blank space. As I remove the space, problem solved.
Slice of problem sdp:
a=ssrc:736062433 msid:media stream 1 audio track                                                                                                 a=ssrc:736062433 mslabel:media stream 1                                                                                                              a=ssrc:736062433 label:audio track 1
Then change Strings to:

```
   private static final String AUDIO_TRACK_ID ="audio_track_1" ;

    private static final String LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID ="media_stream_1" ;``
```